# Why are AWS RDS Events notifications not received while using encrypted SNS topics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

I've set up alerts for snapshot events with RDS Event subscription to use SNS topic ( with email subscription ). Everything worked fine until I've encrypted the topic (SSE) with KMS key.
I've tried "default" key and then I've tried CMK. For CMK I've used Key policy specifying service principal as rds.amazonaws.com with no success. I've also tried adding sns.amazonaws.com as well. Finally I came up with most permitting key policy ( below ) and again with no success.

```
{
            "Sid": "Allow access for Key User (SNS Service Principal)",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "*"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
}
```

I found this area (encrypted SNS) poorly documented and I haven't found clear specifications on which services are supported by encrypted SNS and which are not.
Closest I got is this ( RDS is not listed ):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 5):

Found it:

Only unencrypted SNS topics support RDS event notifications. If you specify an encrypted SNS topic, Amazon RDS can't send event notifications to your topic.

1. Open the Amazon SNS console.
2. On the navigation panel, choose Topics, and then choose the topic that you want to receive an RDS notification.
3. Choose the Encryption tab.
   If you see Configured in the Encryption section, then your topic is encrypted. You also see your AWS KMS key (KMS key) and KMS ARN.

If your topic is encrypted, complete the steps in the Disable encryption from your SNS topic section.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-topics-rds-notifications/

Comment: Apparently it is now supported: https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/new/2022/amazon-rds-support-publishing-events-encrypted-amazon-sns-topics/. Haven't tested this though, and I am not sure if it only works in the Chinese regions.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `events.rds.amazonaws.com` as the service principal in the KMS key policy